# Exception : Invalid Image Data

Tags: flutter, image, dart, visual-studio-code

it's first time i use Flutter , so when i put any image from Network or from the Disk it's show me this Error (Eception : Invalid image Data)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APzhN.png)

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve the Problem >>
you just need to make sure that you are writing the same name in the Folders and same extension

```
 class Home extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('OKay Okay Let\'s go')),
        body: Center(child: Container(child: Image(image: AssetImage('image/asi.JPEG'))))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[this's name of the image's floder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4w1c.png)